# php for Inputbox placeholder does not work as expected

Tags: php, html

I have this code that changed the placeholder of the input box if the input is not correct. but most statements don't work. for example, if i enter nothing, instead of the placeholder being "Password" (which it should be, because nothing is not bigger then 0) it's "Password must be 8 characters or more"

here's my code:

```
<?php

$passwordError = false;
if (isset($_POST['submit-button'])) {
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    if (empty($password) || !preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z!@$%^&*+#0-9]+$/', $password)) {
        $password = true;
    } else {
        $password = false;
    }
};
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<input type="password" id="password" name="password" autocomplete="off" <?php
 if (isset($_POST['submit-button'])) {
if (strlen($password) <= 7 && strlen($password) > 0) {
echo 'placeholder="Password must be 8 characters or more"';} 
elseif (strlen($password) > 128) {
echo 'placeholder="Password must be 128 characters or less"';} 
elseif ($passwordError == false) {
echo 'placeholder="Password"';} 
elseif ($passwordError == true) {
echo 'placeholder="Invalid password."';};} 
else {echo 'placeholder="Password"';}?>>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to be giving the user feedback (if you are doing with the placeholder, that's your choice) using javascript, not php. PHP lives on the server, and won't know about any updates to the input field, which is on the client side. Javascript will run in the browser and will be able to update the placeholder.

Comment: but i'm doing the updates after the user submits the forum, if its not correct, it will change the placeholder. won't it work?

Comment: `$password = $_POST['password'];` gets overwritten with `preg_match`. So `strlen($password)` is on a boolean value.

Comment: @user3783243 Thank you! i didnt notice i was updating $password and not $passwordError